# Activity Feed - choosing the notification in the feed does not navigates the user to the chat with the bot

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I am sending an adaptive card to my bot with notification alert to true. With the flag set to true I am able to receive the message in my bot as well as activity feed. It is mentioned in the documentation that by default if we select notification in activity feed then it should redirect the user to the chat with bot. But selecting the notification in activity feed is not  doing anything.

Following is the sample json of message :

[image]

I have tried the same with deep linking also.

Following is mentioned in documentation:
To navigate the user to content within your tab, your message must include an attachment with a tap action. This tap action should be of type openUrl and have a value that follows the Microsoft Teams deep links format.

I have tried proving tap action for hero card. and open url button action in Adaptive card(tap action is not supported by adaptive card).

What should I do to redirect user to chat with bot when notification is clicked in activity feed ?

Comment: Hey I see from what you posted that you attempted to post a picture of code though it didn't come through.  It would be easier if you just posted your code (copy and paste the actual text) and surrounded it with 3 backticks(`) on the top and bottom to create a code block.

Comment: Hi @Jason..   I am able to see the picture now.

Comment: @neerajsharma Are you trying this for channel messages or personal messages? Clicking on Activity feed opens the conversation with Bot inside a team.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT I am trying for personal user to bot messages. 

Update : I am able to achieve this with Hero Card as it supports tap action. In the above code I changed the tap action type to "OpenUrl" from "Action.OpenUrl" and value to the bot URL. After clicking the notification in activity feed it is redirecting me to the chat with bot.

But I am still trying to achieve it for Adaptive Card. I am seeing adaptive card does not support tap action. So, how to achieve deep linking for notification containing adaptive card ?